# multiple value insert works in mysql procedures?

Tags: mysql, insert, procedure, multivalue

Multivalue insert example - it works manually but NOT in mySQL stored procedure.

```
INSERT INTO input_data1(mobile) VALUES (9619825525),(9619825255),(9324198256),(9013000002),(9999999450),(9999999876) ;
```

i am getting syntax error near "str" word in below proc, Can any one let me know how to implement this multi value INSERT work in procedure?

```
DELIMITER |
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS mobile_series1;
CREATE PROCEDURE mobile_series1(IN str text)  
    LANGUAGE SQL     READS SQL DATA  
    BEGIN    
         DROP TABLE IF EXISTS input_data1 ;  
         CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE input_data1 (mobile varchar(1000)) engine=memory;
         INSERT INTO input_data1(mobile) VALUES str;

    END |
DELIMITER ;
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Must you use a stored procedure here?  It would be better to insert into the temp table directly from your client.

Comment: Yes, I must have to use stored proc as with inserted data i have to GET DATA from some table and return to user. Directly i cannot insert into temp table because values would be provided by application/script.

Comment: I don't understand.  Why can't you insert into the temp table from the application/script?  And perhaps if you showed the query that you're ultimately trying to run, it would be possible to solve it a better way.  See [What is the XY problem?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a MySQL server so there's probably syntax errors and +1 errors (i.e. may not be capturing the last on the list, may not progress past the first item etc, problems fixed by putting a +1 in the code), but you basically want to replace your INSERT statement with something this.

```
DECLARE INT _CURSOR 0;
DECLARE INT _TOKENLENGTH 0;
DECLARE VARCHAR _TOKEN NULL;

SELECT LOCATE(str, ",", _CURSOR) - _CURSOR INTO _TOKENLENGTH;

LOOP

    IF _TOKENLENGTH <= 0 THEN
        SELECT RIGHT(str, _CURSOR) INTO _TOKEN;
        INSERT INTO input_data1(mobile) VALUE _TOKEN;
        LEAVE;
    END IF;

    SELECT SUBSTRING(str, _CURSOR, _TOKENLENGTH) INTO _TOKEN;

    INSERT INTO input_data1(mobile) VALUE _TOKEN;

    SELECT _CURSOR + _TOKENLENGTH + 1 INTO _CURSOR;

    SELECT LOCATE(str, ",", _CURSOR + 1) - _CURSOR INTO _TOKENLENGTH;

END LOOP;
```

Your function call would then be something like

```
EXEC mobile_series1('9619825525,9619825255,9324198256')
```

Comment: Thanks ! problem in above procedure is, for every record it is generating a insert statement and executing it,which would be costly. I need to execute multi VALUE insert in proc. e.g INSERT INTO input_data1(mobile) VALUES (9619825525),(9619825255),(9324198256),(9013000002),(9999999450),(9999999876) ;  while calling function like below way.                                                                 call mobile_series1 ('(9619825525),(9619825255),(9324198256),(9013000002),(9999999450),(9999999876)');

Comment: it's probably not as expensive as you think, the connection and data is all already on the server so there's no additional connection or network latency penalty.

Comment: 88% performance improvement is there if you use MULTI VALUE insert.                                                                 http://ronaldbradford.com/blog/the-value-of-multi-insert-values-2009-06-16/

Comment: "The number one reason for an improvement in performance is the lack of network latency for each command."

Comment: Still needs its solution, couldn't able to insert multiple values into single insert statement  through mysql stored procedure. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: @user1646191 did you try the above solution?