# How can I split string with MySQL?

Tags: mysql, string, split

I have a string like:

```
'11,111'
```

and I would like to get this as 11,111. Is this possible on MySQL?

Comment: Do you really mean split?Coz both of the values seem to be same.

Comment: This is a example, the string also can be as '0,16,319' and i need split for ','

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
set @field='11,111';
select substr(@field,1,LOCATE(',',@field)-1) as col_1,
substr(@field,LOCATE(',',@field)+1,length(@field)-LOCATE(',',@field)) as col_2
```

Answer (score 1):

I wrote an answer earlier in the week where a MySQL procedure split a comma separated list of values into individual values here https://stackoverflow.com/a/12264448/1368730

If you need a more specific answer you'll need to say what you're doing with the split values.